What size storm door do I need?
Need to replace my front door on a mobile home. It is a RH inswing with storm door. The storm door measures 36x75--that's just the door. What size door would I need to fit my rough opening?

What size door do you have now? By definition, that fits... You may find you need to custom order or trim to fit unless you are willing to rip out the entire frame and put in a new prehung door.

You need to measure the width and height of the door itself. Not the screen door.
Mobile home doors are usually smaller than standard doors. (76 inches high instead of 80 inches.) This makes them a bit tougher to find.  However most home centers, and lumberyards either have them or can order them.  Often when there are a number of mobile homes in the area, there are stores that specialize in mobile home products.
How the door is mounted and framed is something that only you know. There are multiple ways that these doors are installed, sometimes dependant on the year the home was manufactured. Take pictures and measurements, especially pictures of the framing around the door and the hinges, to the store where you are purchasing the door. They can help advise you as to the fit.
